# Whats wrong with my code [CSS]

Tags: html, css

I'm not so good with **CSS** to start with, however I'm really looking on improving myself.

Now what I wanted to acomplish is an expandable window, that would fit the size of the content with the animation of expanding.

My main issue is the `#expand:hover` and `rightbut:hover` doesn't work at all. And the fit div to content also doesn't work as when I go animate percentage it doesn't show the animation at all.

I know the code could be a completly miss however I do need you assistance, as I know you all know better than me.

Thank you!
     https://jsfiddle.net/VisualTech48/0r27vgv4/1/

```
    /* Checkbox Hack */

input[type=checkbox] {
  position: absolute;
  top: -9999px;
  left: -9999px;
}

#rightbut {
  position: absolute;
  top: 16px;
  right: 26%;
  color: #7a7a7a;
}

#rightbut:hover {
  color: #dddddd;
}

#expand {
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 150%;
  border-width: 100%;
  backround: #d4d4d4;
  color: #7a7a7a;
  transition: 0.5s;
  /* Animation time */
  -webkit-transition: 0.5s;
  /* For Safari */
}


}
#expand:hover {
  color: #dddddd;
}
label {
  cursor: pointer;
}
p {
  color: black;
}

/* Default State */
div {
  background: #d4d4d4;
  width: 75%;
  height: 35px;
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: 0.8s;
  /* Animation time */

  -webkit-transition: 0.8s;
  /* For Safari */
}

/* Toggled State */
div:hover {
  background: #b2b0b0;
}
input[type=checkbox]:checked ~ div {
  height: 290px;
  background: #fff;
}
```

Comment: I didn't get you exactly..First question ` #expand:hover and rightbut:hover doesn't work at all` what do you want on `:hover`

Comment: Good question... terrible title.  I recommend something like "CSS: Animating Block Height"

Answer (score 0):

[Apparently](http://css3.bradshawenterprises.com/animating_height/), you can't animate `height` to `auto`, but you can animate `max-height` to a fixed number. It'll just fit the text because it's `max-height`

[Demo](http://codepen.io/Ghodmode/pen/obWZMa) at CodePen because it has "tidy" and AutoPrefixer built-in.

```css
#expand {
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 150%;
  border-width: 100%;
  background: #d4d4d4;
  color: #7a7a7a;
  transition: 0.5s;
}

label {
  cursor: pointer;
}

div {
  background: #d4d4d4;
  width: 75%;
  max-height: 35px;
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: 0.5s;
}

div:hover {
  background: #b2b0b0;
  max-height: 5000px;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <label id="expand" for="expand-1">I'm a toggle</label>
  <p>I'm controlled by toggle. No JavaScript!I'm controlled by toggle. No JavaScript!I'm controlled by toggle. No JavaScript!</p>
  <br>
  <p>hi</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Very Simple changes. Changes made in your jsfiddle [Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/0r27vgv4/2/)

> **Modified below css..**

```
  /* Toggled State */
    div:hover{
       background: #b2b0b0;
       height:auto;
    }
    input[type=checkbox]:checked ~ div {
       height:auto;
       background: #fff;
    }
```

> **Added a New Class**

```
input[type=checkbox]:unchecked ~ div {
  // height:290px;
   background: #fff;
}
```